# Does the area of a triangle change when it has a fixed rectangle inside it?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, area

I am solving optimization problems for calculus. One of the problems has a ladder extending over a 10 ft fence, leaning on a house 4 ft from the fence, like so:

| <-house
|
| ------|
| ------| <-fence (10ft)
| -4ft- |

Excuse the poor illustration... The ladder will rest on the fence, extend over the fence and rest on the house. The problem states to find the shortest ladder length (the hypotenuse).

Assumption: When the hypotenuse of the triangle will be the smallest (ie shortest ladder length), the area of the entire triangle will also be the smallest.

My question: is the above assumption true? Does the area of a triangle with a fixed rectangle (4 * 10) ever change? I don't want the solution, just want to know whether to continue with the proof or not, so please just answer whether the assumption is correct. Thinking about it logically, I don't believe the area of the triangle changes, but I may be wrong...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Say more here. What line of thought leads you to think the area of the triangle does not change? And you state two somewhat different assumptions: assuming that the area of the triangle changes is not the same as assuming that the triangle with the least area will also have the shortest hypotenuse.  Are you doubting the assumption the problem asks you to accept, or the more basic assumption that the area of the triangle changes at all?

Comment: I am wondering whether the area of a triangle changes when it runs through a point. If you look at the illustration you included in your answer below, if point E moves left or right and still runs through the point D, does the area of the triangle AEF change? (My intuition is that as E moves left, BED becomes smaller while CDF becomes larger, thus keeping the area the same, same process when E moves to the right). @Edward

Comment: It's true that, as $E$ moves to the left, $\triangle BED$ gets smaller and $\triangle CDF$ gets larger. But not generally by equal amounts.  For example, as $E$ gets very close to $B$, $\triangle BED$ decreases by very small amounts, while $F$ rapidly races upward, giving a large corresponding increase to $\triangle CDF$. Again, as $E$ moves toward $B$, the base of $\triangle AEF$ is always $> AB$, but there's no limit on how great altitude $AF$ can become. Thus the area of $\triangle AEF=\frac{1}{2}AE\times AF$can get as large as you like. Its area is not constant.

Answer (score 0):

[image: minimum ladder]The assumption is true. The area of the triangle does change. As $E$ moves in toward $B$, the area of triangle $BED$ shrinks to nothing, while the area of triangle $CDF$ increases beyond all bounds.  Thus the area of the whole triangle $AEF$, whose hypotenuse is the ladder, is increasing beyond all bounds as $E$ moves in toward $B$, and likewise as $F$ moves down toward $C$. Somewhere between these two infinite ladders is the minimum ladder you seek.